# E-Mail controller - crashes when cancel is touched (but not send)

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, email

I have a very simple implementation of MFMailComposeViewController. It works very well - I pass a string from my app which will be e-mailed and then touch 'send' and the e-mail will send. No problems.

However, if I touch the 'cancel' button, the app will crash (EXC_BAD_ACCESS). Do I have to implement a special method for the cancellation of a MFMailComposeViewController? The send button will automatically do it the right way, but the cancel button won't. What is the difference between the two (except that in one case the e-mail will be sent and in the other it won't)?

Here is my code:

```
    #pragma mark - EMail

-(IBAction)emailCurrentPage:(id)sender {

    NSString *textToBeSend = @"Test";

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer;

    mailComposer=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate=self;
    [mailComposer setMessageBody:textToBeSend isHTML:NO];
    [self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];

    [mailComposer release];

}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {

    if (error) {

        NSString *msgOFF = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"I could not send the e-mail for the following reason: %@", error];
        UIAlertView *alertOFF = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                 initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                 message:msgOFF
                                 delegate:self
                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertOFF show];
        [alertOFF release];
        [msgOFF release];

    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error  {   
    NSString *message = @"";
    // Notifies users about errors associated with the interface
    switch (result) {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            message = @"Mail: canceled";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            message = @"Mail: saved";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        {
            message = @"Mail: sent";

            //Your code


        }
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            message = @"Mail: failed";
            break;
        default:
            message = @"Mail: not sent";
            break;
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Yay, works wonderfully. I guess it's vital to check to all results- something I haven't done. Thanks so much again, you made my day.